# Linux /etc/security/limits.conf equivalent file in Android

Tags: android

In **Linux** we can limit user processes by editing  `/etc/security/limits.conf` file. Is there any equivalent file in **Android** for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an Android developer, but apparently [Android supports cgroups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-kernel/8HlaJNR6Q_o/cTu5MUoLkkgJ)([also](https://code.google.com/p/cgroupmgr/wiki/cgroupsForAndroid)). On regular servers, cgroups are intended to replace several different subsystems (the limits subsys being one) so it's probably (just going off my GNU/Linux admin experience) preferred to use cgroups to do what you're wanting (going forward that's probably a good recommendation on the server-side as well).